# MongoDB C# storing ISODates correctly

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have an application that handles dates correctly however I'm running a backup service which stores the documents somewhere else and I never knew I would have problems importing documents with specific date format. First I don't know how to handle MinValue dates in terms of importing them as I get "`Invalid date format`" when I try to parse `ISODate("0001-01-01T00:00:00Z")` via the mongo shell in Robomongo.

My second issue is that when I try to import some dates that have two decimal places as milliseconds it also fails. It needs to be with 3 decimal places apparently. That way dates such as `ISODate("2020-11-23T09:05:00.01Z")` would fail whereas `ISODate("2020-11-23T09:05:00.010Z")` would work. How can I specify the fact I want to either store or serialize the dates in right format (3 digits for milliseconds) and how to handle correctly null dates?

Note I'm using Mongo c# driver `v2.10.4`

Comment: 1/1/01 is the default date in the constructor so you can always use new DataTime().  You can always parse in c# and then pass results to ISODate.  See : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Date/

Comment: Yup, I get that, however I need to import the dates via the mongoshell that's why I wanted to have the dates in the right format. Like I said, I would need to know if I can configure the Bson settings to avoid serialization of the milliseconds and whether I can serialize as NULL those default dates

Comment: Maybe a custom serialize : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40424387/comparing-dates-in-mongodb-with-c-sharp-linq-driver